# How do I compare using the AVG function in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, One for Workers and One for Departments.

Worker(WorkerID, DeptID, Name, Age, Experience)
Department(DeptID, Name)

I want to find names of Departments that have workers with Average Experience under 5 years.

The query I wrote is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT Department.Name AS DeptName
FROM Department
LEFT OUTER JOIN Worker ON Worker.DeptID = Department.DeptID
WHERE 5 > ( SELECT AVG (Experience)  FROM Workers);
```

This doesn't give me any output or errors. What am I doing wrong?

If i put 5 in quotes as "5", it returns all Departments instead of only those with Avg Experience under 5 years.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking an advice for SQL query - it's better to prepare a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) for your question. You will get an answer more quickly and you'll see if it's right or wrong

Comment: What's wrong with your query: a) You calculate average experience of **all** workers - and you get a number greater or less then 5, b) then you compare 5 > calculated value which will be either always True or always False. "This doesn't give me any output " - that means that average experience is greater than 5. So your predicate becames `WHERE false ` for all records => by itself it's not an error but you get 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong with your query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Department.Name AS DeptName
FROM Department
LEFT OUTER JOIN Worker ON Worker.DeptID = Department.DeptID
WHERE 5 > ( SELECT AVG (Experience)  FROM Workers);
```

A. You calculate average experience of all workers

```sql
 ( SELECT AVG (Experience)  FROM Workers)
```

And you get a value.

This value could greater or less then 5.

B. You compare calculated value with 5

```sql
WHERE 5 > ( SELECT AVG (Experience)  FROM Workers);
```

This predicate will be always False or always True.

> This doesn't give me any output or errors.

So effectively it becames `WHERE False` for all rows.

It's not an error but you get 0 rows for that.

### What I suppose is needed

Notes:

- "I suppose" - in general it advised to prepare a [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com) for question.
- It's better to specify mysql version

You wrote:

> I want to find names of Departments that have workers with Average Experience under 5 years.

Average Experience by department?

Do you need:

```sql
SELECT Department.Name AS DeptName
FROM Department
LEFT OUTER JOIN Worker ON Worker.DeptID = Department.DeptID
GROUP BY Department.Name
HAVING AVG(Experience) < 5
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can do this with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT d.Name AS DeptName
FROM Department d
WHERE (SEELCT AVG(w.Experience)
       FROM Workers w
       WHERE w.DeptID = d.DeptId
      ) < 5;
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, as suggested in the other answer.  This might be a wee bit faster with an index on `Department(DeptId, Experience)`.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach to get the same result (using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`):

I group by department and filter those departments which workers average experience is less than five years.

```
SELECT Department.Name AS DeptName
FROM Department
INNER JOIN Worker ON Worker.DeptID = Department.DeptID
GROUP BY Department.Name
HAVING AVG(Experience) < 5;
```

This query `SELECT AVG(Experience) FROM Worker;` return the average experience of all workers together, not by deparment.